# How to parametrize test scenario example in karate

Tags: cucumber, karate, gherkin

I have to test an API where I have to give various type of speech inputs with similar details in API request body. I can write these different speech using Scenario Outline and Example but I have to parameterize that speech also.

Consider below example:

```
  Scenario Outline: Validate identification
    Given url exampleURL
    And request {"message" : "<speech>"}
    When method post
    Then status 200
    Examples:
    | speech                     |
    | My name is John Doe and the ID is 12345|
    | I am John Doe and ID is 12345          |
```

Is there any way I can pick name and ID from somewhere else maybe from feature file or any external file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, refer to this example:

```
Feature: using a csv file for data-driven testing

  Scenario Outline: dynamic ${__num + 1}
    # dynamic outline comment
    * print 'row:', __row
    
    Examples:
      | read('data.csv') |
```

And in `data.csv` you have:

```
name,age
John,42
Jill,35
```

This will work. Please refer the documentation for `@setup`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master#setup

Here is another example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76527245/143475

Comment: Actually I need to parametrize only name and ID like this -
| My name is <Name> and the ID is <ID>|
| I am <Name> and ID is <ID>                   |

Comment: @mogli3 no you can't inject variables into `Examples`, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57291852/143475 - my advice is don't try to over-complicate things, just keep it simple